# fullcalendar prev / next click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

i add a javascript to catch user click on prev button (to get that month's data)

```
$(".fc-prev-button span").click(function(){
                var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
                console.log("The view's title is " + view.intervalStart.format());
                console.log("The view's title is " + view.name);
                return false;
            });
```

but every time a user click, it will log 3 times, means on click on the button, 3 times call the function, if there is a way to just call 1 time?

or anyone has a better idea to deal with user click on the prev / next button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better use built in events to get your data. You could listen to `viewRender` and get your data like this:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    viewRender: function(view, element) {
        console.log("The view's title is " + view.intervalStart.format());
        console.log("The view's title is " + view.name);
    }
});
```

[`view Render` Documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/)

Probably this will avoid your problem.

Comment: If viewRender is used, dayRender is not getting called for the first time calendar load. it will become a problem if i use some validations( showing day colors) in dayRender callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete span in selector. May be that would help. There are three spans inside of the button...

Comment: there is just one span in that

Comment: sorry - looked wrong to the code in mine.. i tried your script and i have one